# $\frac{1}{x-a}$ is uniformly continuous on (0,b] for each 0<b<a

Tags: real-analysis

I just started studying real analysis. So, I am not sure if my answer is right or not.
I would really appreciate it if you could let me know what mistake I made.

Question: prove $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-a}$ is uniformly continuous on (0,b] for each $0<b<a$.

Definition: $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,b]$ if, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in(0,b]$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

What I tried:

Since $0<x\leq b$, we have $-a<x-a\leq b-a<0$

Since $0<y\leq b$, we have $-a<y-a\leq b-a<0$

So, $(x-a)(y-a)\geq (b-a)^2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{(x-a)(y-a)}\leq \frac{1}{(b-a)^2}$

Then, let $\delta=\epsilon\cdot (b-a)^2$.

For all $x,y\in (0,b]$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|=|\frac{1}{x-a}-\frac{1}{y-a}|=\frac{|x-y|}{(x-a)(y-a)}<\frac{|x-y|}{(b-a)^2}<\epsilon (b-a)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{(b-a)^2}=\epsilon$  .

Thus, it is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks good. Alternatively, you can use Mean Value Theorem, where for some $c \in (x,y)$:
$$
\left|\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y}\right| = |f'(c)| = \frac{1}{(x - a)^2} \leq \frac{1}{(b - a)^2}
$$
So $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \frac{1}{(b-a)^2}|x - y|$, and for each $\epsilon > 0$ the obvious choice for $\delta$ is $(b - a)^2\epsilon$.